# sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: store

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm learning sqlite3 with python, but I've been facing this error: "sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: store". How do I get around this?

```
import sqlite3

def create_table(): #function to create the table
    conn = sqlite3.connect('lite.db')
    cur = conn.cursor() # creating th cursor object
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS store (item TEXT, quantity INTEGER, price REAL)")
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()



def insert(item, quantity, price ): #function to insert into the table
    conn = sqlite3.connect('lite.db')
    cur = conn.cursor() # creating th cursor object
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO store VALUES(?,?,?)", (item, quantity, price))
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

insert("biscuits",500,20000)


def view():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('lite.db')
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM store")
    rows = cur.fetchall()
    return rows
    conn.close()

print(view())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to call the `create_table` method before calling `insert`. As you haven't called the the `create_table` method the `insert` method tries to insert a record to a non existing table.

The solution is simply to call the `create_table` method before `insert` as follows:

```
create_table()    # Add this line before the insert
insert("biscuits", 500, 20000)
```